# How to wrap each group of image and next div in a list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, jquery-selectors

I want to wrap each group of image and next `div`, as in the example:

```
<div class="group">

   <img class="slide" src="...">
   <div class="content">...</div>

   <img class="slide" src="...">
   <div class="content">...</div>

   <img class="slide" src="...">
   <div class="content">...</div>

   ...

</div>
```

to

```
<div class="group">

   <div class="subgroup">
      <img class="slide" src="...">
      <div class="content">...</div>
   </div>

   <div class="subgroup">
      <img class="slide" src="...">
      <div class="content">...</div>
   </div>

   <div class="subgroup">
      <img class="slide" src="...">
      <div class="content">...</div>
   </div>

   ...

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
$(".group .slide").each(function(){
    $(this).next(".content").andSelf().wrapAll("<div class='subgroup' />");
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uy6f261o/)**

Comment: `andSelf()` is depricated in jquery version 1.8 and above. But can get same functionality with `addBack()`

Answer (score 1):

You can get all slide and content element. then slice returned array to form set of element and then wrap it in same group:

```
var childelements = $(".group > .slide , .group > .content");
for(var i = 0; i < childelements.length; i+=2) {
  childelements.slice(i, i+2).wrapAll('<div class="subgroup"></div>');
}
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8y8e3s8y/)**